# Passing props components with React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I would like create article page, linked in blog listing. My route :

```
<Route path = '/blog/:slug' component={Article} />
```

I dont know how i can passing my props data (title, description, etc ..) to my Article components. I'm on MeteorJS projet, and my data is not static, it's with MongoDB.

Do you know if i can passing global object ? :

```
<Route path = '/blog/:slug' component={Article} data={props} />
```

Anyone can help me ? :)

Thank you community !

Answer (score 2):

You can use an inline [`render`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) function instead of `component` and pass props as usual.

As an example, if you want to pass title prop to Article component you can do something like this.

```
<Route path = '/blog/:slug' render={(props)=><Article title="My article title" {...props}/>} />
```

Here `props` is props coming from router like match, location, history and staticContext. You can remove `{...props}` if you don't want them inside your Article component.

Comment: Hi Tharaka, thank you for your response. I understand your solution. But i don't understand on i can passing my data when i clic on my Link :) When I send my data ? My Route is on routes.js, with all my routing. Thank you !

Comment: Since your date will be based on `slug`, you can pass data as props. Because you need to pass different from for different `slug`. The correct approach is load data inside the  `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of Article component.